# Notice: Undefined index | PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to retrieve specific table data from MySQL and using PHP to display the information. Should be simple enough to retrieve the data and print it but I get undefined index only when retrieving the data and trying to display.

I'm retrieving the information and displaying the information in a profile page according to the username in the header.

```
if(isset($_GET['username']))
{
    $username           = $_GET['username'];
    $profile_uid        = $Wall->useriD($username);
    $profile_details    = $Wall->userDetails($profile_uid);
    $friend_count       = $profile_details['friendcount']; //issue here
} else {
    header('Location:404.php');
}
```

I get the undefined index on the $friend_count = $profile_details['friendcount']; but I'm not sure why, I believed everything checked correctly but apparently not. Here is how I'm fetching the information.

```
public function useriD($username)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT uiD FROM users WHERE username = :username AND status='1'");
    $sth->execute(array(':username' => $username));

    if($sth->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        $row = $sth->fetch();
        return $row['uiD'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function userDetails($uiD)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uiD = :uiD AND status='1'");
    $sth->execute(array(':uiD' => $uiD));

    $data = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $data;
}
```

The issue is when I try to display the information such , I've been at it for a few hours and I'm stuck. Any leads would be great.

Comment: do a `var_dump($profile_details)`. you'll see exactly what's available in that array. Note that fetchAll() will return an array-of-arrays, not just one data row as an array.

Comment: Yeah what Marc B says, so its most likely `$profile_details[0]['friendcount']`, but do check.

Comment: You guys are correct. Thank you for the support. I've always wondered what the [0] stands for, is it the current id that's loaded into the header?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only interested in one row, use `fetch()` instead of `fetchAll()`:

```
$data = $sth->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `userDetails` function, fix the last statement:

```
return $data[0];
```

(You might also want to precheck whether `$data[0]` exists, and if it does not, return `NULL`, `FALSE` or throw an exception.)